# Запрос MYSQL где два поля одновременно должны быть равны числу

Tags: mysql, база-данных, запрос

Имеется база с полями `id, sdel, podtv`
Нужно вывести поля где и `sdel!=1` и `podtv!=1`.
Если я пишу запрос через `AND`

```
SELECT * FROM task WHERE id=9 AND (sdel !=1 AND podtv !=1)
```

у меня не выводятся поля, где хотя бы одно поле равно 1. Как правильно его сформировать?

Comment: почему у вас в тексте равно, а в запросе не равно? при этом  сначала пишите, что одновременно равны, а потом хотя бы одно.

Comment: Так *одновременно* или *хотя бы одно*?

Comment: где одновременно не равны 1

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM task WHERE id=9 AND sdel=1 AND podtv=1 LIMIT 1
```

Comment: А лимит зачем? К тому же автор скорее хочет узнать про условие ИЛИ, просто не может правильно задать вопрос.

Comment: @ЕгорБанин затем что если задают такой вопрос, то значит не факт что вовсе знают про автоинкремент и как следствие айди могут повторятся. (хотя кому-то может так и нужно, без уникальности)